# Multiplicity of the eigenvalues of $A+I$ (knowing $A$)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to find the eigenvalues and their multiplicity of $(A+I)$, knowing the eigenvalues and their multiplicity of $A$. (A is non-zero)

For the eigenvalues, I know the trick : there exists a non-zero vector $v$ such that $Mv = \lambda v$. Thus:
$$(M+I)v = Mv + Iv = \lambda v + v = (\lambda + 1)v$$

So $\lambda +1$ is an eigenvalue of $(A+I)$. But how do I prove their multiplicity is also the same ? This might be basic, but I couldn't prove it rigorously...

Also I have another question (a kinda follow-up) : If $M$ is diagonalisable, is $(M+I)$ also diagonalisable ?

Comment: For the multiplicity: think about the corresponding linear independent eigenvectors.

Comment: $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ if and only if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A+I$ with eigenvalue $\lambda + 1$.

Comment: Are you asking about the algebraic multiplicity, or the geometric multiplicity? The geometric multiplicity is easy, because $E_{\lambda}$, the eigenspace of $M$ corresponding to $\lambda$, is equal to the eigenspace of $M+I$ corresponding to $\lambda+1$, by the argument you give. For the algebraic multiplicity, verify that if $p(t)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $M$, then $p(t-1)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $M+I$.